# Java Painting Inconsistencies

Tags: java, repaint, drawimage

I am creating a game that loads images as gameobjects from an arraylist painting only the objects that are in range of the current frame. The problem I am running into is speed inconsistencies from differing amounts of images inside the arraylist at any given time. For example if the character walks into an area with a large number of gameobjects in the area and suddenly comes upon a empty lot my character all of the sudden can sprint because the lightened load. Is there any way to prevent this from happening and smooth out the repainting?

Comment: It seems like you're using the rate of your game loop to determine the speed of movement in which case this kind of behavior is unavoidable. Just as a helpful link: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks great article, but it very depressing that there is no way around it. :(

Comment: Well pretty much the way around it is to start over and use delta time. I know 'start over' is a tough thing to hear.